# I get TypeError: value.sendit is not a function, why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Im trying to build a Quiz game with Websockets and testing somethings right now and got stuck. I need the value.sendit function, but i dont know why it doesnt work. I get TypeError: value.sendit is not a function.

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const PORT = 3000;
let questions, playerCount = 0, msgCounter = 0, currentQuestion = 0, score = 0;
let CLIENTS = new Map();

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: PORT, ClientTracking: true });
wss.generateId = function () {
  return (Date.now() * (Math.random() * 100));
}


wss.on('connection', (ws) => {

  ws.id = wss.generateId();
  CLIENTS.set(ws.id, { connection: ws,
                       answer: null,
                       score: 0,
                       sendit: function() {console.log("Test")}
                       //run: function(msg) { ws.send(msg); }
                     });
  let idMsg = 'id=' + ws.id;
  ++playerCount;
  ws.send(idMsg);

  console.log("[SERVER] New client has connected with id of:" + ws.id);

  ws.on('close', () => { console.log('[SERVER] Client has disconnected'); --playerCount; });

  ws.onmessage = (e) => {
    let str = e.data;
    let msgArray = str.split('&'); //msgArray[0]='id', msgArray[1]='clientType', msgArray[2]='answer', msgArray[3]='score'
    if ( msgCounter < playerCount - 1 ) {
      CLIENTS.set(msgArray[0], {answer: msgArray[2]});
      ++msgCounter;
    } else {
      msgCounter = 0;
      CLIENTS.set(msgArray[0], {answer: msgArray[2]});
      ++currentQuestion;
      let msg;
      CLIENTS.forEach((value, key) => {
        msg = toString(currentQuestion) + '&' + toString(score);
        if (value.answer == 'true') {
          value.score = ++score;
          value.sendit();
        } else if (value.answer == 'false') {
          sendit(msg);
        }
      })
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: `CLIENTS.set(msgArray[0], {answer: msgArray[2]});` this is overwriting the entire object. `CLIENTS.get(msgArray[0]).answer = msgArray[2];`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp How would i change only the answer value ?

Comment: See the second part of my comment: `CLIENTS.get(msgArray[0]).answer = msgArray[2];`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks alot for the tip got it to work now.